# Object has no method getId sencha

Tags: extjs, view, sencha-touch, toolbar

I'm trying to create a view for toolbar in sencha and import it to my file but it keeps on throwing 
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getId'`
Tell me what I am doing wrong. 
I guess it is not allowed to create a view for toolbar only.

view/mainTool.js

```
Ext.define('test.view.mainTool',{

requires:['Ext.field.Search'
  ,'Ext.Toolbar'
],

config:{docked:'top',
ui:'normal',


items:[
  {
xtype: 'searchfield',
    placeHolder: 'Search...',
    left: true,
    id:'mainSearch',
width: 200,

  },
  {
xtype:'button',
ui:'action',

text:'filter',
id:'filter'
  },
  {xtype:'spacer'},
  {
xtype:'button',
ui:'action',
text:'showOnMap',
id:'showOnMap'
  },
  {
xtype:'button',
ui:'action',
iconCls:'arrow_left',
id:'back'
  },
  {
xtype:'button',
ui:'action',
iconCls:'home',
    id:'home'
       }

    ]

  }


});
```

app.js

```
Ext.application({
requires: [
  'Ext.dataview.List',
  'Ext.Panel',
  'Ext.Spacer',
  'test.view.list',
  'test.view.mainTool',
  'Ext.List',
  'test.model.list1model',
  'test.store.list1store'
],
launch : function(){
    list1 =Ext.create('test.view.list');
    list2 =Ext.create('test.view.list');
    list2.setHidden(true);
    maintool=Ext.create('test.view.mainTool');
    Ext.create('Ext.Container',{
      id:'contain',
      layout:'hbox',

      fullscreen:true,
      items:[
   maintool,
    list1,
    {xtype:'spacer'},
    list2
      ]
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: your problem related with `mainTool` that you specified in app.js items section.

Comment: sorry can't, because I can't reproduce the problem. I tried on Sencha Fiddle but no success. Just try to remove `maintool` from items section. You will see error disappear.

Comment: But then my toolbar will not appear, Id I try to add toolbar within app.js then no error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `extend: 'Ext.Toolbar'` to your `test.view.mainTool` class. Do not forget, simply defining a class without extending an Ext component does not create a valid Ext View.

Comment: On doing that the following error is appearing.
`Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null `

Comment: That comes probably from other classes of you, e.g. `test.view.list`. Check this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/UjK8nJWR

Comment: What did you change apart from adding extend, it works now? Please point out my mistake. and can you post that code as answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Nothing else :) (don't forget the comma after `extend: 'Ext.Toolbar'`) and use only the toolbar in your Application.launch() (without other classes that you defined)

Comment: I wouldn't post the entire code, as it is not relevant for your problem.